# Инфекция, но дезинфицировать

Tags: орфография

Я понимаю, что это слова латинского происхождения, но все-таки на них должны распространяться какие-то правила русского языка. Я имею в виду, почему нельзя слово "инфицировать" или "дезинфицировать" проверить словом "инфекция", что было бы логично?
В смысле, почему Е в корне меняется на И?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инф**е**кция и инф**и**цировать  - это, строго говоря, не корень. 
Да, в русском заимствования, если у них нет явных признака *русского* суффикса (или преффикса), логично рассматривать как имеющие основу, состоящую из одного корня. 
Но это в основном для целей элементарной морфологии. Для анализа словообразования и алгоритмов заимствования (включая орфографию и т.д.) такой подход не годится.

Реально произошло так, что оба слова были заимствованны независимо друг от друга, возможно даже, в разное время (хотя время тут не главное). И таким образом закрепились в русском языке с разными вариантами "корня", соответствующих разным латинским суффиксам. Менять тут что-то не имеет смысла, для простоты можно считать, что мы имеем дело с разными корнями, - в "школьных рамках" это вполне приемлемо.

Вот если бы одно слово (инфекция)  было заимствовано, а второе уже было образовано непосредственно в русском, ваша логика безусловно бы сработала.

Answer (score 2):

in-ficio, feci, fectum, ere [facio] 1) смешивать, про- 
пропитывать (aquam aliqua re 0): i. aliquid veneno Just, 
Su отравить что-л.; 2) красить, окрашивать, раскра- 
раскрашивать (i. lanas PM; i. se vitro Cs; aequor infectum 
sanguine H; infecta medicamine facies Pt): arma san- 
sanguine infecta V оружие, обагрённое кровью; infectus 
sole PM загорелый; infectus pallore Cld побледнев- 
побледневший, бледный; i. diem О затмить дневной свет; сапа 
senecta infecit caput Tib старческая седина покрыла 
голову; 3) обучать (aliquem artibus С): i. animos С 
воздействовать (иметь влияние) на умы; 4) напитывать, 
заражать (i. aliquem superstitione T, vitiis Sen, C; i. 
animum desidia; infici opinionum pravitate C): infectum 
scelus V преступная натура.

in-favorabilis, e неблагоприятный (sententia Dig). 
infeci pf. к inficio. 
infectio, onis f [inficio] 1) окрашивание (purpurae 
Ambr); 2) изнасилование, растление (mulieris JV). 
infectlvus, a, um [inficio] красящий Vtr. 
infecto, —, —, are [intens. к inficio] отравлять, воз- 
возмущать (publicam pacem Ap). 
infector, oris m [inficio] красильщик PI, C: i. sucus 
PM краситель. 
I   In-fectus, a, um [facio] 1) несделанный, невыпол- 
невыполненный, несостоявшийся, несовершенный (scelus V): 
re infecta (rebus infectis Nep) discedere Cs уйти, ниче- 
ничего не сделав; infecta victoria L не победивши; facta atque 
infecta V были И небылицы; facta infecta facere погов. 
PI сделанное сделать несделанным (смысл: прошлого 
не воротишь); 2) необработанный, необтёсанный (mate- 
ries Pf): aurum infectum V золото в слитках; 3) невы- 
невыполнимый, невозможный (mira et paene infecta Ap): 
nihil ei infectum ratus SI полагая, что для него нет 
ничего невозможного; wo: damnum infectum Dig ущерб 
(лишь) возможный. 
II  infectus, a, um part. pf. к inficio. 
III infectus, (us) m [inficio] крашение РМ

В словарь лениво глянуть?  Это два разных корневых латинских слова, буква с произносится в двух вариантах, как  Ц и как К.

из этого можно понять, что инфекция это симптом, который лечению не поддается, а инфицирование-просто зараза, простейший метод-кровь отворить, засучив рукава, отворачивать.
Врачило-врач-лекарь со скальпелем. Резанул, спустил в тазик, а кровь там сВОРАЧивается.

Answer (score 1):

По-видимому, эти чередования возникли еще в латинском языке.
in–ficio, feci, fectum, ere [facio]  напитывать, заражать
infecto, —, —, are [intens. к inficio] отравлять, возмущать 
infectus, a, um part. pf. К  inficio.
http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/list.php?letter=I