# Корень слова инфекция

Tags: морфемика

Какой в слове ***"инфекция"*** корень?

1)**Инфекци** - родственное слово "инфекци-онн-ый".

2)**Инфек(ц)** - родственное слово "инфиц-ирова-ть".

3)**Инфекц** - родственное слово "дезинфект-ор"

Comment: инфекци/я    https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/инфекция  В остальных словах усечение основы. Какое?  Разбор каждого из приведенных слов смотрите в Сети.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/infect

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/Инфекция-но-дезинфицировать